# how to rename last part of multiple file in linux

Tags: linux, shell, rename

I want to rename to files from below format to below format . How can i  rename last part ?

```
cheatsheetold1.gz.aux
cheatsheetold2.gz.log
cheatsheetold3.gz.out
cheatsheetold4.gz.pdf
cheatsheetold5.gz.synctex
cheatsheetold6.gz.tex
cheatsheetnew7.gz.aux
cheatsheetnew8.gz.log
cheatsheetnew9.gz.out
cheatsheetnew10.gz.pdf
cheatsheetnew11.gz.synctex
cheatsheetnew12.gz.tex
```

to

```
cheatsheetold1.gz
cheatsheetold2.gz
cheatsheetold3.gz
cheatsheetold4.gz
cheatsheetold5.gz
cheatsheetold6.gz
cheatsheetnew7.gz
cheatsheetnew8.gz
cheatsheetnew9.gz
cheatsheetnew10.gz
cheatsheetnew11.gz
cheatsheetnew12.gz
```

Comment: You can only have one file of the name cheatsheetnew.gz or cheatcheetold.gz in one directory. So this might not work. If you are aware of the restiction: cutting the prefix on multiple files might be done in a for loop: `for file in cheatsheet*; do mv $file ${file%.*}; done` (in `bash`). I'm pretty sure, renaming multiple files has been asked a lot here...

Comment: It definitely has been asked *a lot* of times, and there's quite some detailed answers, the lecture none of which the asker seems to incorporate in their question, so:

Comment: is just literally one of a dozen or more questions that come up as a recommendation once you start typing the title of this question into the "Ask Question" editor.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve. The file names look like input, intermediate files and result of typesetting some kind of TeX documents. The `.gz` before some other ending is confusing. The files `cheatsheetold.gz.pdf` and `cheatsheetnew.gz.pdf` might be the resulting PDF documents. In this case removing `.pdf` from the file name will lead to confusion or maybe even result in problems opening the file. Similar for the other file names.

Comment: It's unclear how you want to handle name collisions arising from removing parts of the filename. For example, if you have both `file1.gz.log` and `file1.gz.aux`, the common prefix `file1.gz` would cause issues, as would a pre-exisiting `file1.gz` file.

Comment: it is just for demo , actually i want to remove after .gz part .

Comment: by "just for demo" do you mean that your actual filenames are nothing like the sample filenames you provided?   if that's the case, how do you expect to get accurate and useful answers when you provide misleading and inaccurate samples?